# The entity type requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call over multiple projects?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am creating an EF3 solution for a project.

I have 3 databases, Venue, Catering & Events.
Whenever I run event I get the error:

> The entity type 'MenuFoodItem' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.

I dont know why this is happening as when I run Catering which is where MenuFoodItem class is located it runs and creates the database perfectly fine.

https://github.com/vortexismlg/ThAmCoAssignment

I have no clue what could be causing this considering Catering works fine on its own?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because EF expects each table to have a `Key` property, by convention, it looks for properties named `ID` or TableNAme+ID ( like `BookId`) to make it `Primary Key`.

If your table does not have a `primary key` you just need to `decorate` your class with `[KeyLess]`  or if you configuring your models by `Fluent api` just use  `eb.HasNoKey();`

Comment: But why does it work fine when it is just creating venues?  This problem is only occuring on events

Comment: In venues, you have defined `[Key, MaxLength(5)]` on Code. this make Code as primary key

Comment: Sorry I meant catering, MenuFoodItem has no key set other than foreign keys in ThAmCo Context. So why does it work there but not in my Events?

Comment: `MenuFoodItem` is a `Join Table` , actually it provides `Many-To-Many` relations. take a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: Yeah I understand that but why is this only a problem when I try and add a migration on Events which has nothing to do with MenuFoodItem yet?